# How to deactivate and reactivate user in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to deactivate and reactivate Azure AD B2C user. I want to implement functionality which toggles Azure AD user status.

Comment: Also to mention, i have gone through some graph API but not able to find specific to alter the status.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If by "deactivate and reactivate" you mean prevent the user from signing in. This is currently only possible for local accounts (not accounts from social providers: Facebook, Google, etc).

You can achieve this by either:

1. The [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), Users and Groups blade > Profile > Settings, Block sign in.
   [image: Profile Blade screenshot]
2. The Microsoft Graph, by sending a PATCH request to the **beta**/users/ and setting the 'accountEnabled' property to false. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update
   [image: Graph Patch User accountEnabled screenshot]

If you'd like to be able to disable sign-in for social accounts as well, vote for the "[B2C Block sign in for social accounts" idea](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/4739dfe1-b625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789) in the feedback forum.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: Can you also flag the question as answered please?

Comment: The feedback link is dead.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan - fixed both links. Replaced the generic one for the feedback forum to the relevant specific feedback entry that was created since the original answer.